# CSS 3 float text top left in keyframe animation

Tags: css, css-animations, angularjs-animation

I've tried many different ways to add text to this keyframe animation, but the problem is that it messes up one of the animations when I include the div containing the text. Ideally, I want the text to be center and top or center and top left, but when I get it there, it throws off the last span in the animation. How can I edit the class waitingtext so that it doesn't interfere with the animation?

[Site where I got the css](http://blog.jpamorgan.com/loading-animations-with-asynchronous-http-requests-in-angular-js/)

HTML

```
 <div class="main-loading" ng-show="mainloading">
          <div class="waitingtext">My text</div> 
       <span class="main-loading"></span><!--
           --><span></span><!--
           --><span></span><!--
           --><span></span><!--
           --><span></span>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
    .waitingtext {

  color:#FFF;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  line-height: 60px!important;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5px;


}
div.main-loading
{
    background: #1b7817;
    opacity:.9;
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -150px 0 0 -200px;
    text-align: center;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;-moz-border-radius:6px;-webkit-border-radius:6px;border-radius:6px; padding-left: 5px
}

div.main-loading
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    line-height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
}

.main-loading span
{
    display: inline-block;

    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 145px 3px 0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);

    animation: wave 2s infinite ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: wave 2s infinite ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: wave 2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes wave
{
    0%, 60%, 100%
    {
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
        transform: translateY(0);
        -moz-transform: translateY(0);

    }

    20%
    {
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
        transform: translateY(13px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(13px);
    }

    40%
    {
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
        transform: translateY(-13px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(-13px);
    }

}

@-webkit-keyframes wave
{
    0%, 60%, 100%
    {
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
        transform: translateY(0);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    }

    20%
    {
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
        transform: translateY(13px);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(13px);
    }

    40%
    {
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
        transform: translateY(-13px);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-13px);
    }
}

.main-loading span:nth-child(1)
{
    animation-delay: 0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;

}

.main-loading span:nth-child(2)
{
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

.main-loading span:nth-child(3)
{
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.main-loading span:nth-child(4)
{
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.main-loading span:nth-child(5)
{
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.4s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with positioning but everything to do with your CSS selectors

`:nth-child()` (what you were using) counts *all* of the children of the parent, including the div you added. What you need is `nth-of-type()`, which only counts the spans

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/u7C2G/)